# '/:routeparams' is overriding other route in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
       templateUrl : 'junk.html',
   })
   .    .when('/:pageuniqueid', {
       templateUrl : 'page.html',
   })
   // route for the about page
   .when('/first', {
       templateUrl : 'first.html',
   })

   // route for the contact page
   .when('/second', {
       templateUrl : 'second.html',
   });
});
```

If i type 'example.com/first' in the URL then instead of getting first.html i am  getting page.html.
I am implementing the page that user can access directly with their dynamic pageid after base URL.
I want to get page.html only if it is not matched with the other routes. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the route definitions matters.

If you define the '/first' route before the '/:pageuniqueid', it should work.

The angular router stops evaluating the routes after the first match.

So in order to get the page.html as a fallback, you should put it as last entry in the list.